# HDMI connection with 360 not working, but confirmed to work on other TVs?

Tags: xbox-360

OK, so here's a tricky question for someone with any knowledge in this department.

I have been playing with my Xbox on a computer monitor for a long time because I have no Wired Internet in my room (don't own a wireless router). Now I want to put it back in my room and plug it into my TV.

So this is where it gets strange. I have had problems with some HDMI cables lately so at first when I plugged it in it didn't do anything, didn't even react. So naturally I thought it was the HDMI. I plugged it into another TV in our house and it didn't work there either. So I went out and bought another HDMI cable. Now, I try again on the TV in my room, and to my despair, there is nothing.

A few things to note about my Xbox and TV here:

- While watching Digital TV with an AV or HDMI device plugged in and running, the TV gets all glitchy and basically looks like the signal is dropping out. This is not the problem but something to note.
- My Xbox is pretty early in the 360 lifespan, and is from the era of the red rings of death. My Xbox does not fully 'turn on' unless it detects an output screen. It goes into a sort of stasis while it looks for a monitor or TV to connect to, and if it can't find one it turns off after about 20 seconds.

So, I get annoyed at the fact that a brand new HDMI cable isn't working and I take it to the other TV I have and attempt to plug it into that. When I turn it on, the swirly Xbox logo comes up and makes the sounds. So I assume I plugged it in wrong in the way or something on my TV. So then I go back in and try again and nothing happens. However if I turn it back to actual TV mode, I get that glitchy sort of chopped up image that lets me know that an external device is connected and sending information to the TV.

So then I connected my Android Tablet to the TV using a HDMI connector I got for it. Plug it in *the exact same port as the Xbox* and to my surprise it spring into life and puts out an image of the tablet.

So I'm super confused. The Xbox and HDMI cable are fine, as I tested them on another TV and a monitor to be sure. The HDMI port on my TV is also fine because everything BUT the Xbox seems to be able to connect to it, including my Desktop.

I also know that the TV and Xbox are compatible because I was playing Xbox on the TV about 3 months ago, and it was fine. I also know that somewhere, somehow, they are 'connected' because when I press X the tray opens, and I can interact with the Xbox (also meaning it's connected somehow because it actually goes to 'full turned on' mode, as opposed to not finding the TV and turning off).

Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your TV is busted.  If the XBox works fine on other devices, with the same HDMI output port and cable, then by process of elimination, it must be your TV.  Do you have another HDMI port on the TV you can test?  It could be just that single connection is faulty.

Comment: Voting to close as user has not been back since asking this.  More information needs to be provided to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by sending too much voltage through an HDMI cable. If you're using an HDMI splitter, for example, you could be using the wrong power adapter.

I lost a splitter and the mini-displayport to HDMI capability (not the cable, the capability) on a graphics card doing just that.

So I'm saying that you could have ruined the HDMI-out port on your Xbox.

Comment: The question specifically states that the HDMI cable works fine through his tablet.  So it's definitely not the cable.

Comment: @fbueckert That's not what I meant. 

Overvoltage can leave the cables unaffected and ruin the devices attached.

Comment: @Glimpse You might want to edit your answer a little to specify that you suspect the Xbox is the part that's broken, not the cable